# Host URL for private api in a hybrid application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use a javascript private API in our hybrid mobile application.
The API uses Host name and 10 digit key to verify the account.

```
Account{
    "host":"sample.example.com",
"key":"1234567890",
```

}

The problem is, my hybrid mobile application doesnot use any host but runs in  the url "`file:///android_asset/www/index.html`"

Please let me know that is there any workaround to solve this issue?